# Fragment Transaction loads a blank view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

The issue appears to be that fragments seem to load in a very strange way in RARE occurrences.

Sometimes the view of a Fragment is NOT visible, onCreateView is called, but it does NOT add the view to the activity, it just loads a blank white page. When onResume is called from resuming the app (such as going to recent applications and clicking my app) the view appears.

ALL fragment transactions are done on the MAIN thread obviously.

This happens approx 1 in every 20 times.

I am happy to supply ANY code you want. So if something is missing then please let me know and I will happily supply it for you

My onCreate in my activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Variables.context = this;
        Variables.activity = this;
        Variables.p_class = HomeActivity.class;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        }

        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
        toolbar.getMenu().clear();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        actionbar_pw_spinner = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_pw_spinner);
        actionbar_pw_mins = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_pw_mins);

        actionBarTitleTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_title);

        usersName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usersName);
        usersEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usersEmail);

        actionBarTitleTV.setText(this.getTitle());

        btnBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_back);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        btnBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btnMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_menu);
        btnMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDrawer();
            }
        });
        btnMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        setPersonInfo();

        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

        Variables.myLocation = new Location("myLoc");
        Variables.myLocation.setLatitude(0.0);
        Variables.myLocation.setLongitude(0.0);

        if (!Variables.isThisBidTaxi()) {
            CustomerComms.myOwnSocket = new MySocket(null);
            CustomerComms.myOwnSocket.start();
        }

        SettingSQLHelper helper = new SettingSQLHelper(HomeActivity.this);
        Variables.setting = helper.getSetting();
        helper.close();

        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();
        buildLocationSettingsRequest();
        checkLocationSettings();

        setTitle("");

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentspace, new SplashFragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            ((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }

        containLayout = null;
        containLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmentspace);

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(getListener());
        m_updateBooking = (Booking) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("booking");

        m_TrackDriver = (Boolean) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("track");

        Variables.initBooking();
    }
```

My onResume in my activity:

```
 protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

        Variables.context = this;
        Variables.activity = this;

        if (m_updateBooking != null) {

            if (m_updateBooking.getJobStatus() == Booking.eeJob_Complete) {
                if (!Variables.driverrated) {
                    DriverRatingFragment DriverRatingFRA = DriverRatingFragment.newInstance(m_updateBooking);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentspace, DriverRatingFRA).addToBackStack(DriverRatingFragment.class.getName()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    ((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

                }
            } else {
                if (m_TrackDriver) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentspace, TrackingDriverFragment.newInstance(m_updateBooking)).addToBackStack(TrackingDriverFragment.class.getName()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    ((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

                } else {
                    gotoMyBooking(m_updateBooking);
                }
            }
        }

        m_updateBooking = null;
        getIntent().removeExtra("booking");
        getIntent().removeExtra("track");

        if (Variables.setting == null) {
            final SettingSQLHelper helper = new SettingSQLHelper(HomeActivity.this);
            Variables.setting = helper.getSetting();
        }

    }
```

My onPause

```
  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

My onCreateView inside a fragment looks like this:

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_booking, container, false);//the rest of my code then follows here
    return inflaterview
        }
```

My activity XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ProgressWheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".Activity.HomeActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_title"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/new_booking"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/button_back"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/back_button"
                            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/button_menu"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/menu_button"
                            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <com.todddavies.components.progressbar.ProgressWheel
                        android:id="@+id/actionbar_pw_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        ProgressWheel:barColor="#86f066"
                        ProgressWheel:barLength="10dp"
                        ProgressWheel:barWidth="1dp"
                        ProgressWheel:rimColor="@color/White"
                        ProgressWheel:rimWidth="2dp"
                        ProgressWheel:textColor="@color/White"
                        ProgressWheel:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/actionbar_pw_mins"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                        android:text="@string/mins"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                </FrameLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentspace"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/White" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My Android Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commandsoftware.androidbookingapp"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.chasesoftware.cabmaster.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api" />

        <receiver android:name=".Activity.SMSReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="@string/fabric_key" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/facebook_api"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I commit a Fragment transaction my code looks like this:

```
((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentspace)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            ((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            ((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentspace, new MyBidsFragment().newInstance(booking)).addToBackStack(MyBidsFragment.class.getName()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            ((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Another example of Fragment Transaction

```
 myBookingsFragment = MyBookingsFragment.newInstance(updateBooking);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentspace, myBookingsFragment).addToBackStack(myBookingsFragment.getClass().getName()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Comment: Please could you provide the code of the `Activity` the `Fragment` exists within?

Comment: My Activity is 1000 lines long, is there any specific part you would like to save copying it all?

Comment: In particular, the `onCreate` and also if you're utilising them, `onPause` and `onResume`.

Comment: onCreate, onPause, onResume all added to the TOP of the post (to keep it easier to read for future people who may answer the question)

Comment: instead of people who seem to have no idea about programming voting to close the question, please tell me why your voting to close the question. Off topic is just plain stupid, I have given all code required, with steps to replicate the issue and the issue that I am having. What more would you like?

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with:

- Replace:

  ```
    ((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentspace)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
              ((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
              ((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentspace, new MyBidsFragment().newInstance(booking)).addToBackStack(MyBidsFragment.class.getName()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
              ((HomeActivity) Variables.context).getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
  ```

  with

  ```
      ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.fragmentspace, new MyBidsFragment().newInstance(booking)).
            commit();
  ```

  (btw, make `newInstance()` `static`, so you won't do this strange initialization of new instance of `MyBidsFragment`)
- Then replace

  ```
   myBookingsFragment = MyBookingsFragment.newInstance(updateBooking);
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentspace, myBookingsFragment).addToBackStack(myBookingsFragment.getClass().getName()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
          getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
  ```

  with

  ```
   myBookingsFragment = MyBookingsFragment.newInstance(updateBooking);
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
             replace(R.id.fragmentspace, myBookingsFragment).
             addToBackStack(myBookingsFragment.getClass().getName()).
             commit();
  ```

  **`replace()`**, not `add()`
- Then I'd do something with the fact, that Activity has 1000 lines of code. It makes code much harder to maintain and understand (+ even post on SO)

I hope, it helps

Comment: I will test this shortly. Sadly not all of the code was written by me, but I am working on getting all the code up to scratch :) What is the difference between replace and add?
For example one of my fragments has a Google Map on it. If I replace that fragment does the map then need to re-load? 
For example, Fragment A has a map..
Fragment A > Fragment B > Press Back button > ? Does map now load again?

Comment: @apmartin1991 replace is a code sugar for "remove"&"add".  On back-press the _view_ will be re-created (though adapters and other in-memory objects, etc. might be still there (if it fragment hasn't been destroyed by system). Google Maps I'm pretty sure has some caching, so re-drawing of the map should be fairly quick. (in most cases it's in your power to make recreation of the view fast :-) )

Comment: I am going to create a a single function to deal with the fragments. I will create a custom class which deals with REPLACING and ADDING fragments. That way if required I can easily modify all fragment stuff so easily. Much easier for future changes. Google Maps may be caching but its defo not loading correctly, but I am sure I can fix that with some time. The rest all seems ok, but only changed 20 Transactions, about 60 more to go!