# Can I move a fragment elsewhere instantly without recreating anything?

Tags: android, android-fragments

This may sound stupid, but can I do that? I have searched a little, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691416/when-to-use-the-attach-and-detach-methods-of-fragmenttransaction) says "Re-attach a fragment ... causes its view hierarchy to be re-created, attached to the UI, and displayed.", probably meaning that the UI of the fragment is recreated losing states and other things.

The reason why I am trying to do is that I would like to achieve something like the Bottom Sheet of Google Maps. The only title part is showed at the bottom, but we can swipe it up and it becomes a Bottom Sheet. I think when only the title part is showing, it is not actually a Bottom Sheet, as it would be difficult to make exactly that part of a Bottom Sheet to be shown. I think Google Maps has put the title part separately, and is replacing it with a Bottom Sheet whose top part looks just like the title part, when swiping up begins.

So, to achieve similar effect, I thought I would create a cluster of UI as a fragment, and when the user begins swiping up, I place a Bottom Sheet with the peek size is set exactly to the height of the fragment, and move the fragment into the top of the Bottom Sheet, so that it can be swiped up.

But I want to keep everything of the fragment without recreating anything, as if I take the fragment and just move into the fragment instantly. Is that possible, or should I save the states and restore them when the fragment's UI is recreated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.** Consider fragment as `View` and play with `ObjectAnimator` or any animation class as per behaviour. (Slide-up animation will do the trick)

Note: Fragment will initialize first even you display 20% of portion over main layout. *State will remain same* This does answers your question i guess.

Here is similar example for your work around. [Reference](https://github.com/mancj/SlideUp-Android)