# Lag when switching tabs in BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that contains a BottomNavigationView, and this bottomnav helps the activity to display three fragments. These fragments load well, and I use an AsyncTask to do every heavy operation, while in the UI thread, I show a ProgressBar until everything loads.
There is a weird behaviour with my fragment: The first time I load the fragment it takes some time to actually display it, instead of displaying it instantly with a progressbar.
This thing only happens the first time, and only in this fragment.
The fragment code only contains this:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        new LoadData(getView(), getContext()).execute();
    }

private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private View v;
        private Context context;

        public LoadData(View v, Context context) {
            items = new ArrayList<>();
            this.v = v;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            setItems(context); //Heavy operation
            adapter = new DashAdapter(items, context);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //shows progressbar
            progress = v.findViewById(R.id.DFProgress);
            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            setPager();
            //sets viewPager and hides progressbar
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

In the gif below, if you look at the bottomnavigationview at the bottom, you can see that it takes time to display the fragment. But after trying to load the fragment a second time, it loads as expected.
[image]

How could I make the fragment to load the right way?

Comment: Are you doing anything else in the Fragment's `onCreate`, `onCreateView`, or the other lifecycle methods?

Comment: Yes, I set up other UI elements

Comment: can you share the code of setPager()?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I have two options.

1. Use postdelay when you call LoadData or
2. First add all fragments with manually. You manage navigationItemSelected yourself.

Like this:

```
val firstFragment: Fragment = FirstFragment()
val secondFragment: Fragment = SecondFragment()
val thirdFragment: Fragment = ThirdFragment()

val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

var active = firstFragment
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, thirdFragment, "3").hide(thirdFragment).commit()
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, secondFragment, "2").hide(secondFragment).commit()
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, firstFragment, "1").commit()

navView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {  }
navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
       when (item.itemId) {
           R.id.navigation_first -> {
               fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(firstFragment).commit()
               active = firstFragment

           }
           R.id.navigation_second -> {
               fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(secondFragment).commit()
               active = secondFragment
           }
           R.id.navigation_third -> {
               fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(thirdFragment).commit()
               active = thirdFragment
           }
       }
        true
   }
```

And remove these lines in your nav_host_fragment:

```
app:defaultNavHost="true"
app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use it with PostDelay?

Comment: There is an examle [here](https://github.com/kasimoz/Weather_Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kasim/weatherAndroid/ui/forecast/ForecastFragment.java). But I think you should use second option.

Comment: But the second option is exactly what I do in my Main Activity

Comment: thanks after more then 3 - 6 hours yours is the only solution that worked

Answer (score 0):

When I tried @Kasım Özdemir 's answer, Each time the activity is launched, There was an initial ripple effect on the first item in bottom navigation view.(because I am using material bottom navigation view, which has a default ripple effect. And also UI was not visible when I tap for the first time, but I think that was because I was using different method than @Kasım Özdemir to change my active fragment when Item is clicked.

I didn't want to start my activity with  first item, but with middle item in navigation view, which is "FragmentTwo" in below case. So the ripple effect was quite irrelevant.

So, I just ***attached*** the fragment instead of *adding* it and then hiding it, and now there is no ripple, Here is how code looks in Kotlin...

```
    val firstFragment: Fragment = FragmentOne()
    val middleFragment: Fragment = FragmentTwo()
    val thirdFragment: Fragment = FragmentThree()
    var fragment: Fragment? = null
    var bnv: BottomNavigationView? = null

    bnv = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)
    bnv!!.selectedItemId = R.id.middle_page

  //fragments attached other than the fragment linked with middle item    
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(firstFragment).commit()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(thirdFragment).commit()

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_main_container, middleFragment())
        .commit()
 bnv!!.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->

            when (item.itemId) {    
                R.id.first_page -> fragment = firstFragment
                R.id.middle_page -> fragment = middleFragment
                R.id.third_page -> fragment = thirdFragment    
            }
    
            if (item.isChecked){
                false
            }

            else {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace(
                        R.id.activity_main_container,
                        fragment!!
                    ).commit()
                true
            }
        }
```

So, using attach can also work fine instead of adding and then hiding it... for more information you can [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691416/when-to-use-the-attach-and-detach-methods-of-fragmenttransaction)

(If you haven't already, Try using Navigation Component for bottom navigation, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50948257/13252809). It is more handy in some case, as it handles default backStack management by itself.)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can use jetpack navigation for simple bottombar navigation

Simple Bottom Navigation with Jetpack Navigation:

Let’s start by including the Jetpack Navigation library in your apps by adding these lines in app’s build.gradle file:

```
def nav_version = "2.1.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

We start by creating a simple bottom navigation flow first. For that, you need to do first add NavHostFragment in your single activity layout file. Add this in the activity_main.xml file inside the FrameLayout tag.

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/fragNavHost"
  android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:defaultNavHost="true"
  app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_nav_graph" />
```

You will see an error saying “Cannot resolve symbol @navigation/bottom_nav_graph .”

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment2">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment2"
        android:name="com.wajahatkarim3.bottomnavigationdemo.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchFragment2"
        android:name="com.wajahatkarim3.bottomnavigationdemo.SearchFragment"
        android:label="fragment_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/notificationsFragment2"
        android:name="com.wajahatkarim3.bottomnavigationdemo.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment2"
        android:name="com.wajahatkarim3.bottomnavigationdemo.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
</navigation>
```

Its time for add some code in our activity class. Open MainActivity.kt file, and create a method setupViews() in it. Call this in onCreate() of the activity. Add these lines in the setupVeiws() method.

```
    fun setupViews()
{
    // Finding the Navigation Controller
    var navController = findNavController(R.id.fragNavHost)

    // Setting Navigation Controller with the BottomNavigationView
    bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    // Setting Up ActionBar with Navigation Controller
    // Pass the IDs of top-level destinations in AppBarConfiguration
    var appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        topLevelDestinationIds = setOf (
            R.id.homeFragment,
            R.id.searchFragment,
            R.id.notificationsFragment,
            R.id.profileFragment
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```

Comment: this doesn't really fix the issue

Comment: I using  Jetpack Navigation and problem is not resolved