# Stop BottomNavigationView from Recreating Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

My bottom navigation view with Navigation Component is recreating my fragments each time I navigate. I would like a Singletop, how can I do this?

I followed this tutorial: https://proandroiddev.com/android-navigation-arch-component-a-curious-investigation-3e56e24126e1

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setupNavigation()
    }

    private fun setupNavigation() {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.mainNavigationFragment)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() =
            findNavController(R.id.mainNavigationFragment).navigateUp()
}
```

Comment: I had answered a question. You can look [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60407969/8956604)

Comment: I would still like to use the navGraph. Your approach is bypassing that.

Comment: I did research on this subject just like you. I couldn't find anything other than this way. If you find it, write it down. Good luck.

Comment: there is no way to do this. I 've been searching for days